# Play paused event before continuing with Click

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, onclick, event-handling

I have a video that pauses at a state with several buttons. If you click one of the buttons, it plays the video and pauses to an open state showing information. From here the user can click on any of the other buttons or background. What I am trying to do is when a user clicks another button, finish playing the close then open the clicked item. I want it to be more of a fluid movement, right now the old state disappears abruptly and the click event begins.

```
stop();

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2);
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void { gotoAndPlay(58); }
function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_3(event:MouseEvent):void { gotoAndPlay(92); }
```

Comment: in your click event handler, you are telling it to immediately leave and go to another frame.  You said you want it to "finish playing the close".  What does that mean?  Do you have a close animation playing on the info that opens?  If so, you could add an event listener (EFFECT_END) on the animation then in that handler, gotAndPlay(58).  If not, what is it exactly you want the user to see on screen before going to frame 58?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a timeout function the the MouseEvent.

```
function fl_ClickToPlayVideo_2(event:MouseEvent):void {
    play();
    setTimeout(playThis,700);
    function playThis() {
       gotoAndPlay(58);
    }
}
```